# Finding the sum of eigenvalues of a matrix depending on the parameters

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, matrix, mathematical-optimization, eigenvalues

There is a system that has the following Hamiltonian: $H=-\frac{1}{2}\Delta-\frac{1}{r}+\frac{B^2}{8}\rho^2-\frac{B}{2} (m + 2 m_s)$, where $r=(\rho,z,\phi), B=5, m=0, m_s=-1/2$. To find the eigenvalues, I would like to use Gaussian functions as a basis set.

The basis set: $\psi_{ij}=e^{-b_{j} z^2}e^{-a_{i} \rho^2}$ , where $a_{i}=a_1 * qa^{i-1}$, $i=1, 2 ,3,..., i_{max}$ and $b_{j}=b_1 * qb^{j-1}$, $j=1, 2 ,3,..., j_{max}$ are geometrical progressions.

I would like to minimize the sum of eigenvalues of the system (minimization in four parameters $a_1, b_1, qa, qb$).

Below is the code in which I am trying to find the eigenvalues of the system `Eigenvalues[{EE[a1, b1, qa, qb], normm[a1, b1, qa, qb]}]`

If I understand correctly, then the Mathematica cannot find the eigenvalues due to the complicated expressions. Is there any other way to find the sum of the eigenvalues (In order to further minimize)?

In the code I rename $\rho\equiv r$

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

imax = 3; jmax = 5;
geoseq[init_, r_, n_] := init*r^(n - 1);

Psi[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_, r_, z_, i_, j_] := 
  Exp[-geoseq[b1, qb, j]*z^2]*Exp[-geoseq[a1, qa, i]*r^2];


Kk[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_, r_, z_, i1_, j1_, i2_, j2_] = 
  FullSimplify[
   Psi[a1, b1, qa, qb, r, z, i2, j2]*
    Laplacian[Psi[a1, b1, qa, qb, r, z, i1, j1], {r, \[Theta], z}, 
     "Cylindrical"]];
Kk1[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_, i1_, j1_, i2_, j2_] = -1/2 2 Pi*
   Integrate[
    Kk[a1, b1, qa, qb, r, z, i1, j1, i2, j2] r, {r, 
     0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
    Assumptions -> {a1 > 0, b1 > 0, qa > 0, qb > 0, i1 > 0, j1 > 0, 
      i2 > 0, j2 > 0}];
Kx[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_] = 
  Table[ Kk1[a1, b1, qa, qb, i1, j1, i2, j2], {i1, 1, imax}, {i2, 1, 
    imax}, {j1, 1, jmax}, {j2, 1, jmax}];
KK[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_] = Flatten[Kx[a1, b1, qa, qb], {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}];

B = 5; m = 0; ms = -1/2;
VC[r_, z_] := -1/Sqrt[r^2 + z^2];
Px1[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_, i1_, j1_, i2_, j2_] = 
  2 Pi*Integrate[
    Psi[a1, b1, qa, qb, r, z, i2, 
      j2] *(VC[r, z] + 1/8 B^2 r^2 + B/2 (m + 2 ms))*
     Psi[a1, b1, qa, qb, r, z, i1, j1]*r, {r, 
     0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
    Assumptions -> {a1 > 0, b1 > 0, qa > 0, qb > 0, i1 > 0, j1 > 0, 
      i2 > 0, j2 > 0}];
Px[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_] = 
  Table[Px1[a1, b1, qa, qb, i1, j1, i2, j2], {i1, 1, imax}, {i2, 1, 
    imax}, {j1, 1, jmax}, {j2, 1, jmax}];
PP[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_] = Flatten[Px[a1, b1, qa, qb], {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}];

EE[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_] = KK[a1, b1, qa, qb] + PP[a1, b1, qa, qb];

(*normalization*)
int[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_, i1_, j1_, i2_, j2_] = 
  2 Pi *Integrate[
    Psi[a1, b1, qa, qb, r, z, i2, j2] *
     Psi[a1, b1, qa, qb, r, z, i1, j1]  r, {r, 
     0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
    Assumptions -> {a1 > 0, b1 > 0, qa > 0, qb > 0, i1 > 0, j1 > 0, 
      i2 > 0, j2 > 0}];
norm[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_] = 
  Table[int[a1, b1, qa, qb, i1, j1, i2, j2], {i1, 1, imax}, {i2, 1, 
    imax}, {j1, 1, jmax}, {j2, 1, jmax}];
normm[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_] = 
  Flatten[norm[a1, b1, qa, qb], {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}];

Eigenvalues[{EE[a1, b1, qa, qb], normm[a1, b1, qa, qb]}]
```

Comment: The sum of the eigenvalues is equal to the [trace of the matrix](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tr.html). Is this what you need?

Comment: @Roman, thanks! Yes, the trace of the diagonal matrix `Eigenvalues[{EE[a1, b1, qa, qb], normm[a1, b1, qa, qb]}]` But unfortunately Mathematica does not diagonalize this expression

Comment: What I mean is that you don't need to diagonalize. I'll write down a solution.

Comment: @MamMam It is not clear what do you try to compute?

Comment: @Alex Trounev, thanks for the question! I would like to get an analytic expression for the sum of the eigenvalues (which depends on 4 parameters `a1, b1, qa, qb`). And then minimize this expression. But the problem is that Mathematica cannot do the inversion operation for the matrices greater than `imax=3, jmax=4`

Comment: @Alex Trounev, earlier, you showed me how to solve this problem using ground state minimization https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285177/optimal-basis-set-of-gaussian-functions-for-describing-a-quantum-system-part-2. But there is a problem of a large number of variational parameters. For example, if I consider imax= 4 and jmax=5, then these are 20 + 4 variational parameters and minimization takes a very long time. Therefore, I decided to try to minimize the sum of eigenvalues, but in this case, as written above, Mathematica cannot obtain an analytical expression

Comment: @MamMam Maybe we need some advanced numerical method to compute ground state for large `imax, jmax`?

Comment: @Alex Trounev, thanks! Could you please explain in more detail what you mean? Do you mean a more efficient method of finding the minimum with a large number of variation parameters than the Minimize and FindMinimum? So that I can formulate the question (I am asking about  advanced numerical methods)

Answer (score 6):

The sum of the eigenvalues can be calculated without diagonalizing the matrix.

Example: generate random $n\times n$ Hermitian matrices:

```
n = 7;
A = # . ConjugateTranspose[#] &[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, n, 2}] . {1, I}];
B = # . ConjugateTranspose[#] &[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, n, 2}] . {1, I}];
```

Sum of generalized eigenvalues:

```
Total[Eigenvalues[{A, B}]]
(*    184.183    *)
```

Direct calculation without diagonalization:

```
Tr[A . Inverse[B]]
(*    184.183 + 4.84945*10^-13 I    *)
```

Chopping off the numerical-precision imaginary part:

```
Re[Tr[A . Inverse[B]]]
(*    184.183    *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but in my case, the matrix `normm[[a1, b1, qa, qb]]` depend on four parameters and Mathematica cannot perform the inversion operation. The matrices are parameter dependent because I would like to then minimize the sum of the eigenvalues

Comment: If `normm` cannot be inverted, then your generalized eigenvalue problem is invalid. Invertibility of the matrix $B$ is a pre-condition.

Comment: Thanks! I think in my case this is due to the fact that the expressions are very large. Is there a way to do the inversion of a large matrix in parts, i.e. sequentially working with its components?

Answer (score 2):

First we need to test code with known parameters from my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285177/optimal-basis-set-of-gaussian-functions-for-describing-a-quantum-system-part-2). Please, pay attention that your code has been updated.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

imax = 3; jmax = 4;
geoseq[init_, r_, n_] := init*r^(n - 1);

Psi[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_, r_, z_, i_, j_] := 
  Exp[-geoseq[b1, qb, j]*z^2]*Exp[-geoseq[a1, qa, i]*r^2];


Kk[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_, r_, z_, i1_, j1_, i2_, j2_] = 
  1/2 FullSimplify[
    Psi[a1, b1, qa, qb, r, z, i2, j2]*
      Laplacian[Psi[a1, b1, qa, qb, r, z, i1, j1], {r, \[Theta], z}, 
       "Cylindrical"] + 
     Psi[a1, b1, qa, qb, r, z, i1, j1]*
      Laplacian[Psi[a1, b1, qa, qb, r, z, i2, j2], {r, \[Theta], z}, 
       "Cylindrical"]];
Kk1[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_, i1_, j1_, i2_, j2_] = -1/2 2 Pi*
   Integrate[
    Kk[a1, b1, qa, qb, r, z, i1, j1, i2, j2] r, {r, 
     0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
    Assumptions -> {a1 > 0, b1 > 0, qa > 0, qb > 0, i1 > 0, j1 > 0, 
      i2 > 0, j2 > 0}];
Kx[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_] = 
  Table[Kk1[a1, b1, qa, qb, i1, j1, i2, j2], {i1, 1, imax}, {i2, 1, 
    imax}, {j1, 1, jmax}, {j2, 1, jmax}];
KK[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_] = ArrayFlatten[Kx[a1, b1, qa, qb], 2];

B = 5; m = 0; ms = -1/2;
V[r_, z_] := -1/Sqrt[r^2 + z^2] + 1/8 B^2 r^2 + B/2 (m + 2 ms);
Px1[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_, i1_, j1_, i2_, j2_] = 
  2 Pi*Integrate[
    Psi[a1, b1, qa, qb, r, z, i2, j2]*(V[r, z])*
     Psi[a1, b1, qa, qb, r, z, i1, j1]*r, {r, 
     0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
    Assumptions -> {a1 > 0, b1 > 0, qa > 0, qb > 0, i1 > 0, j1 > 0, 
      i2 > 0, j2 > 0}];
Px[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_] = 
  Table[Px1[a1, b1, qa, qb, i1, j1, i2, j2], {i1, 1, imax}, {i2, 1, 
    imax}, {j1, 1, jmax}, {j2, 1, jmax}];
PP[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_] = ArrayFlatten[Px[a1, b1, qa, qb], 2];

EE[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_] = KK[a1, b1, qa, qb] + PP[a1, b1, qa, qb];

(*normalization*)
int[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_, i1_, j1_, i2_, j2_] = 
  2 Pi*Integrate[
    Psi[a1, b1, qa, qb, r, z, i2, j2]*
     Psi[a1, b1, qa, qb, r, z, i1, j1] r, {r, 
     0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
    Assumptions -> {a1 > 0, b1 > 0, qa > 0, qb > 0, i1 > 0, j1 > 0, 
      i2 > 0, j2 > 0}];
norm[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_] = 
  Table[int[a1, b1, qa, qb, i1, j1, i2, j2], {i1, 1, imax}, {i2, 1, 
    imax}, {j1, 1, jmax}, {j2, 1, jmax}];

U[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_] = ArrayFlatten[norm[a1, b1, qa, qb], 2];


Eigenvalues[{EE[a1, b1, qa, qb], 
   U[a1, b1, qa, qb]} /. {a1 -> 1.3576595084125154`, 
   b1 -> 10.362298171005488`, qa -> 2.6994994668291183`, 
   qb -> 0.19513529311168284`}]//Chop//Sort 

(*{-1.37695, -0.146211, 1.5772, 5.09045, 6.16749, 7.94828, 13.9307, \
20.2562, 22.5456, 24.3574, 25.8672, 37.5024}*)
```

As we know exact value for the ground state is  -1.380398866427, and in this model is about -1.37695. The first excited state (2s) =-0.193746709717, while in this model -0.146211.

Now if we increase dimension as `imax = 3; jmax = 5;` then we have with the same parameters out

```
{-1.37695, -0.187666, -0.0121764, 1.68325, 5.09161, 6.11695, 6.29631, \
8.054, 14.0402, 20.3601, 22.5507, 24.3334, 24.5055, 25.9772, 37.615}
```

We see, that the ground state energy is not improved, but the first exited state looks much better. Let take `imax = 3; jmax = 6;`, then we have

```
{-1.37695, -0.188485, -0.0650577, 0.0163966, 1.70671, 5.09187, \
6.11618, 6.23224, 6.32403, 8.07739, 14.0644, 20.383, 22.5519, \
24.3326, 24.4742, 24.5367, 26.0015, 37.6399}
```

As we can see the second excited state is about -0.0650577, while state  (3 d (m = 0)) = -0.07365. For `imax = 3; jmax = 7;` we have

```
{-1.37695, -0.188638, -0.0659596, -0.0271467, 0.0227442, 1.71189, \
5.09193, 6.11603, 6.23139, 6.26886, 6.33015, 8.08256, 14.0698, \
20.3881, 22.5521, 24.3325, 24.4733, 24.5155, 24.544, 26.0069, 37.6454}
```

We can compare with

ground state (1 s) = -1.3793 (exact value = -1.380398866427)

the first excited state (2 s) = -0.19335 (exact value = 
-0.193746709717)

the second excited state (3 d (m = 0)) = -0.07365

the third excited state (3 s) = -0.03835
Finally note, that with this model we can compute for instance `imax = 15; jmax = 15;` with 4 lowest states `{-1.37851, -0.189091, -0.0665601, -0.0284486}`.

So this is a good model even without optimization `a1, b1, qa, qb`. We can optimize parameters for `imax=3,jmax=4`as follows

```
var = Join[{a1, b1, qa, qb}, 
  Flatten[Table[c[i, j], {i, imax}, {j, jmax}]]]; vec = 
 Flatten[Table[
   c[i, j], {i, imax}, {j, 
    jmax}]]; 
a[1] = a1; 
b[1] = b1; Do[a[i] = a[i - 1] qa, {i, 2, imax}]; Do[
 b[j] = b[j - 1] qb, {j, 2, jmax}]; con = 
 
 sol = 
 NMinimize[{vec . Re[EE[a1, b1, qa, qb]] . 
    vec, {vec . Re[U[a1, b1, qa, qb]] . vec == 1, a1 > 0, b1 > 0, 
    qa > 0, qb > 0}}, var]

(*Out[]= {-1.37452, {a1 -> 1.37897, b1 -> 3.48613, qa -> 2.61302, 
  qb -> 0.458814, c[1, 1] -> 0.0262767, c[1, 2] -> -0.220731, 
  c[1, 3] -> -0.0629083, c[1, 4] -> -0.399011, c[2, 1] -> -0.113762, 
  c[2, 2] -> -0.0347169, c[2, 3] -> -0.169213, c[2, 4] -> 0.128463, 
  c[3, 1] -> -0.460221, c[3, 2] -> 0.493378, c[3, 3] -> -0.201538, 
  c[3, 4] -> 0.0150695}}*)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You are using the sequence parameters from the previous answer. But if I understand correctly, the parameters are not quite the same as in the previous answer. The parameters from previous answer: a1 -> 1.39282, b1 -> 19.9993, qa -> 3.4335, qb -> 0.252195, the parameters used here: a1 -> 1.3576595084125154, b1 -> 10.362298171005488, qa -> 2.6994994668291183, qb -> 0.19513529311168284

Comment: There are so many answers, but it does not matter what optimal combination we used. For instance for `a1 -> 1.39282, b1 -> 19.9993, qa -> 3.4335, qb -> 0.252195` and `imax = 29; jmax = 37;`  we have ` {-1.37924, -0.186864, -0.0663546, -0.0302142}`. Probably we should play with $n_r, n_z$ to get better results.

Comment: Thanks! I realized that the parameters can be changed to find the best combination. Previously, I have changed the parameters in many ways, just manually, significantly and not significantly, I wanted to understand how to change the parameters in order to find the best energy values, but I could not find any dependence of the parameters. I would like to clarify, is this really true? In any case, it's needed to use some way to optimize the parameters?

Comment: @MamMam We can optimize parameters with respect to known values of energy `{-1.3804, -0.193747, -0.07365, -0.03835}`. For example, at `imax=8; jmax=8` optimized parameters are `{a1, b1, qa, qb}={1.2774, 21.0146, 1.82603, 0.271406}`.

Comment: How can we find the optimized values of the parameters if we do not know the energy of the system?

Comment: @MamMam Do you mean optimize with your code?

Comment: Yes. But maybe I didn't understand correctly. You got the parameters `{1.2774, 21.0146, 1.82603, 0.271406}` knowing the correct energy values. And if we assume that they are unknown?

Comment: We define these parameters once for a given combination `imax=8, jmax=8`. Then we can use it for any base. If you are looking for the method how to optimize parameters from the scratch, then read attentively paper  Excited states in variational Monte Carlo using a penalty method :)

Comment: @MamMam See last code in my answer for optimization.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, minimization is very well suited for not very large basis sizes. But in order to find, for example, the third excited level, it is necessary to use a large size of the basis, then the minimization will take a huge amount of time

Comment: @MamMam Yes, you are right. It is why we need code to minimize without `NMinimize`. Could you explore some code in any language adopted to this problem? Then we can translate it into Mathematica .nb.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I do not have some code of minimization for this problem in any other language. Maybe it would be more efficient to use the variational Monte Carlo with a penalty method for this task, which is described in the article that you recommended earlier? I can create a question on how to apply this method for this task?

Comment: @MamMam Python code for quantum Monte Carlo uploaded on https://github.com/WagnerGroup/pyqmc

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to run this code

Comment: Is it better to take questions about translating code from python to wolfram mathematica on mathematica.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @MamMam Before translating, please test is it good for your problem.